# Modify data in cell after listbox filled cell

Tags: excel, listbox

I have a listbox that opens when I double-click the cell. When I select multiple items in the listbox and hit okay it will put these items in the cell. BUT if I want to go to the cell afterwards (select cell and hit F2) and modify the entry it will add my modification but also duplicate what the listbox put in there before. I just want the modification. How can I stop the duplication?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim lType As Long
Dim strList As String
Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error Resume Next
   lType = Target.Validation.Type
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If lType = 3 Then
   Cancel = True
   strList = Target.Validation.Formula1
   strList = Right(strList, Len(strList) - 1)
  strDVList = strList
  frmDVList.Show
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
----------------------------
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
Dim strSep As String
strSep = "; "
  Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
Else

  newVal = Target.Value
 Application.Undo
 oldVal = Target.Value
 Target.Value = newVal
  If newVal = "" Then
  Else
        If oldVal = "" Then
           Target.Value = newVal
        Else
           Target.Value = oldVal & strSep & newVal
        End If
   End If

End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have an event that fires a macro? If so, can you please include your code?

Comment: Two actually: the first opens the UserForm, the secnd just allows me to select from a dropdown list in cell and add to existing entries by using the dropdown function again. In both cases I cannot enter the cell manually (F2) and modify it bc when I do and hit enter it also adds the existing dropdown selection one more time (so it is in there twice):

Comment: Please see code above...